# OpenSSO Fedlet with PHP

Tags: php, federated-identity, opensso

Is it possible to use the OpenSSO fedlets with PHP (or tech. other than Java or .Net) to Enable to enable Identity Federation?

Is there any examples of using fedlets implementing with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - currently the fedlets are for Java or .Net only. There is [simpleSAMLphp](http://rnd.feide.no/simplesamlphp), though, a related project which targets PHP explicitly.